# unable to load image on UIimageView Controller after accessing cameraroll and selecting image in iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I'm stuck with a bit tricky scenario today. I followed the tutorial under http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPad_Camera_and_UIImagePickerController_Application_%28Xcode_4%29

This tutorial has helped me to access camera and camera roll if the coding is done under ViewController.h and ViewController.m.

If I try to create a new UIViewController and name it as "camera" and try to put the same code inside it and try to access through button action from ViewController.m, the cameraviewcontroller loads the view and camera, camera roll also functions but when I select a particular image the view redirects.

```
@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Camera"];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];


}

//camera.h//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
@interface Camera :UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>

{
    UIToolbar *toolbar;
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    UIImageView *imageView;
    BOOL newMedia;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;

- (IBAction)useCamera: (id)sender;
- (IBAction)useCameraRoll: (id)sender;

@end

//camera.m//

#import "Camera.h"

@interface Camera ()

@end

@implementation Camera
@synthesize imageView, popoverController, toolbar;

- (IBAction) useCamera: (id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                  nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker
                                animated:YES];
        newMedia = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction) useCameraRoll: (id)sender
{
    if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
             UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
            [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                      nil];
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

            self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                      initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

            popoverController.delegate = self;

            [self.popoverController 
             presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
             animated:YES];
            newMedia = NO;
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIBarButtonItem *cameraButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                     initWithTitle:@"Camera"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                     target:self
                                     action:@selector(useCamera:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *cameraRollButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                         initWithTitle:@"Camera Roll"
                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                         target:self
                                         action:@selector(useCameraRoll:)];
    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cameraButton,
                      cameraRollButton, nil];
    [toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
    NSString *mediaType = [info
                           objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = [info
                          objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        imageView.image = image;
        if (newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,  
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                              message: @"Failed to save image"\
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

I have googled to find the solutions however I was left with no Solution,kindly help me to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance.